# Will multiple similar wireless devices interfere with each other?

Tags: design, interference

At my church, the singers (3 on most days, up to 5-6 maximum) are "wired" into our audio system. (There is a cable that extends from the myMix output stations directly into earphones, 3.5mm jack). Unfortunately this cable limits the movement of the singers, which isn't something we want.

I've come across [the Audiomate AM8112 unit](http://audiomate.com.au/products.html) ([spec sheet](http://audiomate.com.au/specification.html)) that appears to be what we need to make this work, but I'm concerned about interference from many units running simultaneously. Will this be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a wireless in-ear monitoring option you need to look at something more along the lines of [this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/758339-REG/Shure_P2TR215CL_P2TR215CL_Wireless_In_Ear.html?gclid=Cj0KEQjw6OOoBRDP9uG4oqzUv7kBEiQA0sRYBGv7IdNpvhnpK-HfbqRAXldbnyh5bphFtSQWNiK7jWsaAltm8P8HAQ). Using a Bluetooth transmitter can introduce delay in the system since the signal needs to be digitized, transmitted then converted back to an analog wave form.

But to answer your direct question no they should not interfere but its hard to say as it depends how they are built. Bluetooth should have discrete connections from device to device but I cant say I have personally tested anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's support forum](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201171#12),

> The official Bluetooth specifications state seven is the maximum number of Bluetooth devices that can be connected at once. However, three to four devices is a practical limit, depending on the types of devices and profiles are used. Some devices require more Bluetooth data, so they are more demanding than other devices. Data-intensive devices may reduce the total number of devices that can be active at the same time. If a Bluetooth device becomes slow to connect or does not perform reliably, reduce the total number of connected devices.

So depending on how the audio is digitised, you could have a problem with more than 3 or 4, but in any case 7 looks like a maximum.

**However**, and this is a pretty big however, you are **not** looking at a bluetooth device, but a 2.4GHz Frequency Hopping Spread Spectrum device. Which is what 802.11 and WiFi are. This device doesn't specify either 802.11 or WiFi, so it may not behave as well as devices with the standard specification, but you certainly have bandwidth for many devices to connect at once.

Be aware though, that there may be manufacturer limitations that are specific to them, and you'd best check to see if it conflicts or interferes with any wifi in the building.